# How can I compare two lists in python and return not matches

Tags: python

I would like to return values from both lists that not in the other one:

```
bar = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]
foo = [ 1,2,3,6 ]

returnNotMatches( a,b )
```

would return

```
[[ 4,5 ],[ 6 ]]
```

Comment: Great. What have you tried so far

Comment: What should the result for  `bar = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; foo = [1,2,3,5,6]` be?

Comment: Are you tied to using lists? Would a `set` be possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
def returnNotMatches(a, b):
    return [[x for x in a if x not in b], [x for x in b if x not in a]]
```

Answer (score 59):

One of the simplest and quickest is:

```
new_list = list(set(list1).difference(list2))
```

BONUS!
If you want an intersection (return the matches):

```
new_list = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

Comment: hey @user3885769 I believe your two lines of code are identical

Comment: This is significantly faster than iterating through both lists as per the chosen answer. Comparing two lists with ~200,000 uuids went from 5+ mins to subsecond for me.

Comment: If you use list() constructor, you don't need to use [].

Answer (score 5):

This should do

```
def returnNotMatches(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    return [list(b - a), list(a - b)]
```

And if you don't care that the result should be a list you could just skip the final casting.

Comment: This will discard duplicates in `a` or `b` that are not matched by the other.

Comment: It will, but comparing matches with duplicates makes little sense.

Comment: Unless it has sense... I don't think you can assert that it doesn't have a purpose without knowing the application.

Comment: "I would like to return values from both lists that not in the other one" clearly means to treat the list as a set.

Comment: With the literal wording, `[4, 5, 6]` would be the desired output. I added the comment to the question about sets because it might be that they askee should be using a set as their data structure to begin with.

Comment: As OP has not specified whether duplicates and order need to be preserved, I think this answer is preferable to the top answer since it is more efficient (O(len(a) + len(b)) v.s. O(len(a) * len(b)))

Answer (score 1):

I might rely on the stdlib here...

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

import difflib

def returnNotMatches(a, b):
    blocks = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b).get_matching_blocks()
    differences = []
    for b1, b2 in pairwise(blocks):
        d1 = a[b1.a + b1.size: b2.a]
        d2 = b[b1.b + b1.size: b2.b]
        differences.append((d1, d2))
    return differences

print returnNotMatches([ 1,2,3,4,5 ], [ 1,2,3,6 ])
```

which prints:  `[([4, 5], [6])]`

This compares the sequences as streams and finds the differences in the streams.  It takes order into account, etc.  If order and duplicates *don't* matter, then `sets` are by far the way to go (so long as the elements can be hashed).

Comment: o.o While `difflib` is a cool library, is this a bot post? at first glance this code looked real, and `pairwise` is an interesting function, but it isn't used, `differences` isn't used, and the code throws a `ValueError`...

Comment: @JaredGoguen -- I disagree... Finding the matching blocks of in the sequence when the sequences are different lengths and the length of the different blocks of unmatching values are different is quite non-trivial (especially considering that the answer isn't even necessarily _unique_).  Hence the existence of `difflib` :-)

Comment: @JaredGoguen --Thanks, obviously hacking code together and not keeping  things updated...

Comment: `NameError: name 'size' is not defined` still

Comment: I'm personally curious about that code (which is why the successive comments), not trying to nitpick. I think you might be answering the wrong question though, the answer by zondo is Pythonic and correct (albeit, possibly inefficient, but readability should not often be sacrificed for efficiency in Python).

Comment: @JaredGoguen -- I fixed the size error and posted a complete working example :-).  I'm under the impression that OP actually cares about the order of things.  e.g. if there are duplicates, those should matter.  Maybe I'm wrong -- and if order doesn't matter, then sets are definitely the way to go...

Comment: Would you mind explaining what this code does? For example, `returnNotMatches([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 3, 6])` returns `[([], [4]), ([4, 5], [6])]`. What are these differences? Why is there an empty list in there? Also, it seems like OP does not care about order; to be honest, order didn't even cross my mind until you brought it up.

Comment: @JaredGoguen It's returning the differences in the stream.  Each difference is another tuple returned.  So, this is saying that the second stream has a `4` where the first stream has nothing -- In other words, there's an extra `4` in the second stream.  Later on, the first stream has a `4` then a `5` but the second stream has a `6`.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. Interesting that the function is non-commutative, but I suppose it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension and zip

```
''.join([i[0] for i in zip(a, a.lower()) if i[0] == i[1]])
```