# Comparing two lists on Python

Tags: python, list

I need help comparing two lists and returning the indices that they don't match.

```
a = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
b = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

indices 4 and 8 don't match and i need to return that as a list `[4,8]`

I've tried a few methods but they haven't worked for me.

Comment: See your question answered already here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713093/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-not-matches

Comment: That will certainly help, but that's not a duplicate, OP wants the indexes not the values.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both lists at the same time and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices during iteration, and write a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that filters out the indices where the list values  don't match:

```
>>> [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if x != y]
[4, 8]
```

Comment: PO = [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)) if x!= y]
 
    return PO           This always returns [0] as my result despite the lists having obvious differences

Comment: @dfairch I'm 99.999% sure that this code works correctly. Could you share the two lists you're comparing? (But to be honest I think it's more likely that there's a bug hiding somewhere else in your program.)

Comment: lst1 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]      lst2=[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: @dfairch That gives `[4, 8]` as it should. Really, there must be a bug somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use a simple loop which scans the lists, item by item:

```
a = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
b = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

diff=[]

for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i]!=b[i]:
        diff.append(i)

print diff
```

A list comprehension could also do the same thing:

```
diff=[i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i]!=b[i]]
print diff
```

Comment: `range(0,len(a))` could be simplified to just `range(len(a))`

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, `numpy` provides one way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
b = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])

res = np.where(a != b)[0]

# array([4, 8], dtype=int64)
```

Relevant: [Why NumPy instead of Python lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/why-numpy-instead-of-python-lists)

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip :

```
a = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
b = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

count=0
indices=[]
for i in zip(a,b):
    if i[0]!=i[1]:
        indices.append(count)

    count+=1

print(indices)
```

output:

```
[4, 8]
```